# Sum of Values based on bits enabled Verilog

Tags: verilog, fpga, hdl

I am new to Verilog, I was trying to write a simple code but I am not sure how to do it in a expert way.
I have a 12 bit register "data", each bit of that register have a specific value. e.g.

```
Bit 0 = 12;
Bit 1 = 16;
Bit 2 = 33;
......
Bit 11 = 180;
```

Now if any bit of "data" register is 1 then the result should be the sum of all value that coresponds to that bit value. e.g.

```
data = 12'b100000000101
result = 225 (180+33+12)
```

Right now i am checking each bit of data, if it is 1 then i register that corresponding value and add it to previous registered value. This method takes number of cycles.
How can i do it in a fast way in verilog.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "fast". Presumably you mean time, but remember that time=cycles/frequency - reducing the number of cycles will often reduce the maximum frequency your circuit can operate at.

For example, here's a circuit that does the entire add in one cycle:

```
always@(*) begin
    tempsum = 0;
    tempsum = tempsum + (data[0]? 12:0);
    tempsum = tempsum + (data[1]? 16:0);
    tempsum = tempsum + (data[2]? 33:0);
    //...
end
always@(posedge clock)
    result <= tempsum;
```

If you synthesized this circuit, you'd see a long chain of adders. In could calculate the result in a single cycle, but would have a long critical path, and therefore have a lower fMax. Whether this would be "faster" is impossible to know until you synthesize it (there are too many factors to guess).

A better multi-cycle approach could be to use a tree, i.e.:

```
reg [31:0] sum [29:0];
always @ (posedge clock) begin
    // level 0
    sum[0] <= (data[0]? 12:0) + (data[1]? 16:0);
    sum[1] <= (data[2]? 33:0) + (data[3]? 40:0);
  // ...
    sum[15] <=  (data[30]? 160:0) + (data[31]? 180:0);
    // level 1
    sum[16] <= sum [0] + sum [1];
    sum[17] <= sum [2] + sum [3];
  // ...
    sum[23] <= sum [14] + sum [15];
    // level 2
    sum[24] <= sum [16] + sum [17];
    sum[25] <= sum [18] + sum [19];
  // ...
    // level 3
    sum[28] <= sum [24] + sum [25];
    sum[29] <= sum [26] + sum [27];

    result <= sum [28] + sum [29];
end
```

All that said, ultimately the "fastest" approach will also depend on the other requirements of your system, what you're implementing it on, etc.

Comment: I check your first one cycle solution and yes it is doing all addition in one cycle and its a big chain.

Comment: I also check your second logic and i am going with it. I am implementing it on spartan 3.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like below :-

```
    reg [15:0] sum;
    always @(*)begin    
       for (i=0;i<12;i++)begin
         if (data[i]) 
         sum = sum+Bit[i];
       end //for
    end //always
    assign finalSum = |data ? finalSum: 'h0;
```

Comment: Your `for` loop needs to be inside some sort of `always` block.

Comment: Thanks @wilcroft. Earlier, I just wanted to provide him general idea about it. I have corrected it as suggested by you.

Comment: Your assignment to finalSum won't work either - it needs either an `assign` statement or to be in a block as well. Please try to avoid posting incomplete answers, which includes solutions that won't compile/synthesize without structural changes.

Comment: Thank you for the logic.